# Images from ftp are displayed in mozilla but not displayed in chrome

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am working in a project in which I am getting the images from ftp.

My problem is that when the application is run in Mozilla the images are displayed and I gave the user name and password that is set in app.config, but in chrome the images are not displayed.

Please help that the images are will be displayed and I would not give the p=user name and password.

Comment: without actually looking and understanding the problem how can we help you?